# Time complexity of Depth First Search

Tags: graphs, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, trees, graph-traversal

Please forgive me for asking a novice question, but I'm a beginner at algorithms and complexities, and it's sometimes hard to understand how the complexity for a specific algorithm has come about.

I was reading the DFS algorithm from *Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen*, and this was the algorithm:

```
G        -> graph
G.V      -> set of vertices in G
u.π      -> parent vertex of vertex u
G.Adj[u] -> adjacency list of vertex u


DFS(G)
1   for each vertex u ∈ G.V
2       u.color = WHITE
3       u.π = NIL
4   time = 0
5   for each vertex u ∈ G.V
6       if u.color == WHITE
7         DFS-VISIT(G,u)

DFS-VISIT(G,u)
1   time = time + 1            // white vertex u has just been discovered
2   u.d = time
3   u.color = GRAY
4   for each v ∈ G.Adj[u]      // explore edge u
5       if v.color == WHITE
6           v.π = u
7           DFS-VISIT(G,v)
8   u.color = BLACK            // blacken u; it is finished
9   time = time + 1
10  u.f = time
```

It then said lines `1-3` and `5-7` are `O(V)`, exclusive of the time to execute the calls to `DFS-VISIT()`. 
In `DFS-VISIT()`, lines `4-7` are `O(E)`, because the sum of the adjacency lists of all the vertices is the number of edges. And then it concluded that the total complexity of `DFS()` is `O(V + E)`.

I don't understand how that came about. `DFS-VISIT()` is called *inside* `DFS()`. So, if lines `5-7` of `DFS()` are `O(V)` and `DFS-VISIT()` is `O(E)`, then shouldn't the total time complexity of `DFS()` be `O(VE)`?

Comment: Cormen is only the first listed author.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! Your question is a very basic one. Let me direct you towards our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599) which cover some fundamentals you seem to be missing in detail. Please work through the related questions listed there, try to solve your problem again and edit to include your attempts along with the specific problems you encountered. Good luck!

Comment: Could you give the exact quote of the text you don't understand? If it literally says "exclusive of the time to execute the calls to `DFS-VISIT()`" then that already answers your question: "exclusive of `DFS-VISIT()`" means that the time stated does not include the time taken by `DFS-VISIT()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The book is counting the number of times each line is executed throughout the *entire* execution of a call of DFS, rather than the number of times it is executed in each call of the subroutine DFS-VISIT. Perhaps the following simpler example will make this clear:

```
PROCEDURE A(n)
1  global = 0
2  for i from 1 to n:
3      B(i)
4  return global

PROCEDURE B(i)
1  global = global + 1
```

In each execution of A, line 1 of B is executed $n$ times, and B itself is executed $n$ times. Nevertheless, the running time is $O(n)$ rather than $O(n^2)$.

Here is another example, in which an array $T[1\ldots n]$ is involved.

```
PROCEDURE COUNT(n, T[1...n]):
1  count = 0
2  index = 1
3  while index <= n:
4    ADVANCE()
5    count = count + 1
6    index = index + 1
7  return count - 1

PROCEDURE ADVANCE():
1  while index <= n and T[index] == 0:
2    index = index + 1
```

The procedure COUNT counts the number of 1s in the input array T. Even though ADVANCE could be called up to $n$ times by COUNT and the worst-case running time of ADVANCE is $O(n)$, lines 1–2 of ADVANCE run at most $n$ times, and so the overall running time is $O(n)$ rather than $O(n^2)$.

Comment: Um... I still can't understand. Time complexity for `B()` is `O(1)`, so if `i` is called from `1 to n`, then it's n-times `O(1)` -> `O(n)`.
You say line 1 of B is executed *n* times and B itself is executed *n* times, but aren't they the same thing?

Comment: They are the same thing in this example, but not in the case of DFS.

Comment: I added another example which is more similar to what happens in DFS.

Comment: Yuval sir@ i have got a doubt.In your provided Example algorithm, what if $A$  is called $n$ times which implies $O(n^{2})$.sir please help me out !

Comment: The running time of A doesn't depend on how many times it is called.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus sir ,that was my main point .Sir as per i know got to know (by your answer) ,that if we consider **complexity** of $DFS()$, it will be $O(n)$, but if we combine $DFS()$ ( i mean i am considering it for $n$ vertices) then complexity will be $O(n^{2})$.Am i right sir?

Comment: Running a $\Theta(f(n))$ procedure $g(n)$ times takes time $\Theta(f(n)g(n))$.